# Returning list from one function to another

Tags: python

I am trying to return New_List to main() and print it out. The end goal is to assign New_List to FirstList after it has been sent through change_list. What am I doing wrong? Getting `NameError: name "New_List" is not defined`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
def main():
    FirstList = []
    print("Here is the list of random integers...")
    for x in range(0,12):
        FirstList.append(random.randint(50,100))
    for x in FirstList:
        print(x,end=" ")
        if x == FirstList[4]:
            FourthElm = FirstList[3]
        if x == FirstList[4]:
            NinthElm = FirstList[9]
    print(f"\nThe 4th Element in the list is {FourthElm}")
    print(f"The Element at index 9 is {NinthElm}")
    print(f"The smallest element in the list is {min(FirstList)}")
    change_list(FirstList)
    print(New_List)

    


def change_list(x):
    New_List = x[3:9]
    print(f"The size of the list is now {len(New_List)}")
    New_List = sorted(New_List)
    return New_List
    
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `change_list(FirstList)` with `New_List = change_list(FirstList)`. If you don't assign a variable, it doesn't exist in the scope of the function you try to call it in.

Answer (score 0):

`New_List` only exists within the `change_list` function.  When you call `print(New_List)`, Python doesn't know where to find it.  You'll want to look into **[Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)**.

At this point you have 2 options to change your code:

Option 1

```
change_list(FirstList)
print(FirstList)
```

Option 2:

```
New_List = change_list(FirstList)
print(New_List)
```